# Can someone help to understand how to use handleChainIndexClient?

Tags: haskell, plutus-pab

I'm not guru with Eff system under Haskell.
What i got that method could contains the constraints for monad that should be used with.

```
module ChainIndexHelper
where


import Plutus.ChainIndex.Client
import Plutus.ChainIndex.Effects (ChainIndexQueryEffect (..))
import Control.Monad.Freer.Reader
import Control.Monad.Freer
import Control.Monad.Freer.Error

-- import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import Control.Monad.Trans

import Plutus.V1.Ledger.Scripts (DatumHash, Datum)
import Data.Function ((&))

import Network.HTTP.Client (newManager, defaultManagerSettings)

import Servant.API
import Servant.Client

testGetDatum :: DatumHash -> IO (Maybe Datum)
testGetDatum dh = do
    manager' <- newManager defaultManagerSettings
    let
        reqDatum = DatumFromHash dh
    mbDatum <- runM
               $ runError
               $ runReader (mkClientEnv manager' (BaseUrl Http "localhost" 9083 ""))
               $ handleChainIndexClient reqDatum
    return mbDatum -- Might be post processing stmts
```

For scripts I have to get Datum of previous UTxO so I want to use Chain Index server and call client code. Then I'm constructing pure Cardano Tx. Signing should be on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

A little dummy. Can be improved

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators              #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds                  #-}

...

runClientError :: Eff (Error ClientError ': r) a -> Eff r (Either ClientError a)
runClientError = runError

runHandleChainIndexClient :: DatumHash -> IO (Maybe Datum)
runHandleChainIndexClient dh = do
   manager' <- newManager defaultManagerSettings
   let
      clientEnv = mkClientEnv manager' (BaseUrl Http "localhost" 9083 "")
      reqDatum = DatumFromHash dh
   mbDatum <- runM
              -- $ runError
              $ runClientError
              $ runReader clientEnv
              $ handleChainIndexClient reqDatum
   case mbDatum of
       Left _ -> return Nothing
       Right d -> return d
```